# JQuery não encontra form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, wordpress

Estou utilizando um form da seguinte forma:

```
<form name="mapping_marc" method="post" id="mapping_marc">
        <?php foreach ($all_properties_id as $compound_name => $sub_properties) {?>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 meta-title no-padding' name="<?= $compound_name?>" id="<?= $compound_name?>"> <?= $compound_name?> </label>
            <?php foreach ($sub_properties as $name => $id){?>
                    <label class='col-md-6 col-sm-12 meta-title no-padding'style="text-indent: 5%;"> <?= $name?> </label>
                    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-12 meta-value'>
                            <select name="<?= $name ?>" class='data form-control' id="<?= $name ?>">
                                <?php foreach ($all_marc_fields as $field) { ?>
                                    <option name="<?= $field ?>" id="<?= $field ?>" value="<?= $field ?>"><?= $field ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg tainacan-blue-btn-bg pull-right" id="mapping_save"><?php _e("Save", "tainacan"); ?></button>
 </form>
```

E o JQuery assim:

```
$("#mapping_marc").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#modalImportLoading').modal('show');
    $('#progressbarmapas').remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#src').val() + '/controllers/collection/collection_controller.php?operation=save_mapping_marc',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {form: new FormData(this), collection_id: $("#collection_id").val()},
        success: function (elem) {
            if(elem.result)
            {
                window.location = elem.url;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

O formulário é inserido por meio de uma action do WordPress. Dessa forma o JQuery não encontra o formulário mas seu eu colocar um onclick no botão do form que chama uma função que executa esse jquery então eu consigo encontrar o formulario mas a operação new FormData(this) me retorna um erro. O que pode estar fazendo que o JQuery não encontre o formulário?

Comment: Não sei se vai funcionar @AndreAr, é um palpite, mas tente assim: `new FormData($(this))`.

Comment: O erro persiste

Comment: O form é carregado na tela dinamicamente?

Comment: Sera que poderia colocar o html do form apos ser gerado pelo PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar [.on('submit')](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ao inves de [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$(document).on( 'submit', '#mapping_marc', function (event) { /* etc */ });
```

Dessa forma, mesmo que o formulário entre mais tarde na página o evento vai funcionar porque ele foi adicionado ao `document`, não a um elemento inexistente no carregamento da página.

Answer (score 0):

As vezes o javascript executa antes do seu formulario estar carregado, assim não adicionado seu evento ao formulario e pode ser que seja isso. use dessa forma:

```
$(function(){ //executar somente quando o html for totalmente carregado
  $("#mapping_marc").on("submit", function(){
    //código
  })
})
```